# Pandas add a static date to a series

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I don't know how to add a static date to a a time series:

The serie in string look like this:

```
time_s=pd.Series(['000329','000458','154259','232810'])
```

I convert it in time serie:

```
time_s=pd.to_datetime(time_s,format='%H%M%S')
```

But the date is contained in the name of the file :

```
date_file=datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
```

The simple "way" doesn't work:

```
date_file+time_s
```

I tried to create a series with the static date and add both:

```
serie_date=[pd.to_datetime(date_file) for x in range(len(time_s)) ]
pd.Series(serie_date)+time_s
```

Someone can help me please? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join strings from datetime first and then generate datetimes:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(date_file.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + time_s,format='%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S')
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Merge the strings and next convert to a serie is perfect. I was focus on the format datetime.